# Android browser can't open our website sometimes

Tags: android, networking

Have tried with several Android phones, the browser on the phone can't open our website in a period(maybe several minutes), but the browser of Iphone or Pc can do that during that time.

The problem will happen only when I use the Wifi in my company, never see the problem at home.

There is no problem to Ping our server via adb shell of the android phone when it's browser can't open our website.

In order to find the problem, I use HttpUrlConnection to access our server and see that the HttpURLConnection.connect() method will fail because of TimeoutException when the browser can't open our website.

I think the problem is very strange, why the problem won't happen to Iphone or PC? I don't want to think the android phone is worse than those devices.

Please help me to solve this problem, any suggestion will be appreciated.

More Info:

I use wireshark to capture the packets and see that there's no tcp response for the browser's tcp handshake in the period when the website can't be opened by android phone browser. Any possible reasons?

Comment: Do you use proxy for that wifi?

Comment: @Naresh No proxy is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem long ago. It's a server problem and we solved it by change the following two kernel parameters of our linux server: net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle and net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps.

Here you can find the description of the two parameters: http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-tweaking-121